# web2py getting invalid function after adding new action to controller

Tags: python, web2py

I've inherited an existing web2py application and am unable to add a new action to an existing controller.  To test, I added a new action named "manage_watermark"

```html
def manage_watermark():
    return locals()
```

very simple...just want to first test if I can add a new action however I consistently get 
"invalid function (config/manage_watermark)" when trying to access the new action.  Existing actions work fine but no matter what I do, new actions aren't recognized.

Another test I did was to create a new application and added the same action and things work fine...just not in the existing application.  What am i missing?

web2py 2.8.2-stable+timestamp.2013.11.28.13.54.07
(Running on Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the application has been bytecode compiled, so although you are changing the .py controller file, the .pyc compiled file is remaining unchanged. In the admin app, select "Remove compiled", and then re-compile the app with the new code.